# Copy file from the obtained path to a domain

Tags: c#

Hi all is it possible to copy a file from the path obtained to the domain, I tried as follows but I am getting an exception as `uri formats are not supported`.. So can some one help me how to copy the file

```
 string filePath = "D:\\Folder\\filename.jpg";
 FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
 if (fileInfo.Exists)
 {
    path = "http://WWW.somedomain.com";
    string temppath = path + "/Temp" + "/" + fileInfo.Name;
    if (!File.Exists(temppath))
    {
      var uri = new Uri(temppath);
      File.Copy(filePath, uri.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Pawan thanks, but my requirement is I am calling a service from javascript so this will not work

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the existence of file on the server. This is not possible using `File.Exist` method as it doesn't supports the URI. This method expect the relative path and checked the existence on machine (physical location).

In this case you should use `WebRequest` and get the response from the server. If server returns 404 then your file doesn't exist on the serve or you can check the Content Length.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(temppath));
request.Method = "HEAD";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()

var contentLength = response.ContentLength;

if (contentLength < 0)
{
    // file doesn't exist.
}
```

Comment: How can I check for file as per you said, can you give me a sample

Comment: @demouser you can send the full path of the file in uri section. For ex. `temppath` in this case. See the update.

Comment: Hi sachin how can I copy if not exists?

Comment: @demouser you can't upload file to the remote server using `File.Copy` method. Your server should expose a web service to you by which you can upload the file on the server.